# How to find day of week in php in a specific timezone

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I am confused while using php to handle date/time.

What I am trying to do is this: When a user visits my page I am asking his timezone and then displaying the 'day of week' in his timezone.

I don't want to use the browser's day.
I want to do this calculation in php.

This is how I am trying to achieve it:

1. The timezone entered by user
2. Unix time stamp  calculated by php time() function.

But I dont know how to proceed...
How would i get the 'day of week' in this timezone.

Answer (score 149):

```
$dw = date( "w", $timestamp);
```

Where $dw will be 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday) as you can see here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Since php 5.1.0 you can use `date("N", $timestamp)` to get `1..7` values starting from Monday. In the older versions you can use the trick `(date("w", $timestamp) + 6) % 7` to get `0..6` values starting from Monday.

Comment: I'm very confused.  How does this have so many votes?  The question is how to get the day of the week in a specific timezone, not the webserver's time zone, and not GMT.  This answers the first part of the question, but completely ignores the second part of the question.

Comment: @tfinniga, I think the reason is that many people come to this question when searching how to get the day of the week(as I did), and then vote it up, because it answers their question :)

Comment: Be aware that date() and mktime() only work as long as you move within the UNIX era (1970 - 2038 / 0x0 - 0x7FFFFFFF in seconds).
Use new PHP "Date and Time Related Extensions"

Comment: @dav Wow, you're probably right, but that seems like a really bad reason.  I feel like I'm starting to develop strong opinions about the average php developer.

Answer (score 118):

My solution is this:

```
$tempDate = '2012-07-10';
echo date('l', strtotime( $tempDate));
```

Output is: `Tuesday`

```
$tempDate = '2012-07-10';
echo date('D', strtotime( $tempDate));
```

Output is: `Tue`

Comment: This works beautifully. I used date('D', strtotime($DATE)). My $DATE variable was already in the correct format. I used this to identify DOW in a reporting database I made. When searching across multiple dates, having that little extra DOW abbreviation is nice.

Answer (score 28):

I think this is the correct answer, just change `Europe/Stockholm` to the users time-zone.

```
$dateTime = new \DateTime(
    'now',
    new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Stockholm')
);
$day = $dateTime->format('N');
```

> ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in PHP 5.1.0)
>   1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

For a list of supported time-zones, see
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 20):

Thanks a lot guys for your quick comments.

This is what i will be using now.
Posting the function here so that somebody may use it.

```
public function getDayOfWeek($pTimezone)
{

    $userDateTimeZone = new DateTimeZone($pTimezone);
    $UserDateTime = new DateTime("now", $userDateTimeZone);

    $offsetSeconds = $UserDateTime->getOffset(); 
    //echo $offsetSeconds;

    return gmdate("l", time() + $offsetSeconds);

}
```

Report if you find any corrections.

Answer (score 9):

Another quick way:

```
date_default_timezone_set($userTimezone);
echo date("l");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you can get their timezone offset, you can just add it to the current timestamp and then use the [gmdate](http://php.net/gmdate) function to get their local time.

```
// let's say they're in the timezone GMT+10
$theirOffset = 10;  // $_GET['offset'] perhaps?
$offsetSeconds = $theirOffset * 3600;
echo gmdate("l", time() + $offsetSeconds);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$myTimezone = date_default_timezone_get();
date_default_timezone_set($userTimezone);
$userDay = date('l', $userTimestamp);
date_default_timezone_set($myTimezone);
```

This should work (didn't test it, so YMMV). It works by storing the script's current timezone, changing it to the one specified by the user, getting the day of the week from the `date()` function at the specified timestamp, and then setting the script's timezone back to what it was to begin with.

You might have some adventures with timezone identifiers, though.

Answer (score 2):

"Day of Week" is actually something you can get directly from the php date() function with the format "l" or "N" respectively. Have a look at
[the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

edit: Sorry I didn't read the posts of Kalium properly, he already explained that. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

**Check date is monday or sunday before get last monday or last sunday**

```
 public function getWeek($date){
    $date_stamp = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)));

     //check date is sunday or monday
    $stamp = date('l', $date_stamp);      
    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    //start week
    if(date('D', $timestamp) == 'Mon'){            
        $week_start = $date;
    }else{
        $week_start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Last Monday', $date_stamp));
    }
    //end week
    if($stamp == 'Sunday'){
        $week_end = $date;
    }else{
        $week_end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Next Sunday', $date_stamp));
    }        
    return array($week_start, $week_end);
}
```

Comment: While this may have uses, it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Based on one of the other solutions with a flag to switch between weeks starting on Sunday or Monday

```
function getWeekForDate($date, $weekStartSunday = false){

    $timestamp = strtotime($date);

    // Week starts on Sunday
    if($weekStartSunday){
        $start = (date("D", $timestamp) == 'Sun') ? date('Y-m-d', $timestamp) : date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Last Sunday', $timestamp));
        $end = (date("D", $timestamp) == 'Sat') ? date('Y-m-d', $timestamp) : date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Next Saturday', $timestamp));
    } else { // Week starts on Monday
        $start = (date("D", $timestamp) == 'Mon') ? date('Y-m-d', $timestamp) : date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Last Monday', $timestamp));
        $end = (date("D", $timestamp) == 'Sun') ? date('Y-m-d', $timestamp) : date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Next Sunday', $timestamp));
    }

    return array('start' => $start, 'end' => $end);
}
```

Comment: While this may have uses, it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('l', strtotime('today'));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.