# How to get a day of the week for a selected date using PHP?

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find day of week in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712761/how-to-find-day-of-week-in-php)

I want to get the day of the week of the selected date. For example 05/19/2011 = **Thursday**

Answer (score 11):

Here's how to do it for the **current** time:

```
$day=strftime("%A",time());
```

Or for a specific date:

```
$day=strftime("%A",strtotime("2011-05-19"));
```

Comment: I have a question about your approach. I have `$date =date("d.m.y", time() - 60 * 60 * 120);` as date and want the weekday like you did with `$day = strftime("%A", strtotime($date));` but it returns the same weekday, no matter what I substract from `time()`. I am a little bit clueless here.

Comment: @SatelliteSD - see http://pastebin.com/mne3qhtG  You were passing your formatted string from calling date().  You need to just pass in the calculated date.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
// below first parameter is lowercase "L"
$day_of_the_week = date('l', strtotime($your_date));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `date()` and `strtotime()`.

```
date('l', strtotime($date));
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/qysesZLG).

Answer (score 0):

Use date and strtotime function. More about [**DATE**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
#date("format", int_timestamp);
#date("l", strtotime($date) );
$day= date("l", strtotime("05/19/2011") );
```