# Avoiding if statements when displaying content based on weekdays (PHP)

Tags: php, if-statement, dayofweek

Is there a reason or a way to avoid if statements in a situation like this where I need to display content based on which day of the week it is?

```
$d=date("w");
if ($d=="0") echo "Sunday";
if ($d=="1") echo "Monday";
if ($d=="2") echo "Tueday";
if ($d=="3") echo "Wednesday";
if ($d=="4") echo "Thursday";
if ($d=="5") echo "Friday";
if ($d=="6") echo "Saturday";
```

Comment: Could be... `echo date('l');`?

Comment: I also need to display different content whether it's morning, midday or evening. So different content for monday morning, monday evening, tuesday morning, tuesday evening, and so on.

Comment: That's a really simple approach and can't be ported in a different language or timezone. For example in Europe the first day of the week it's Monday. I suggest you to use a proper library, check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712761/how-to-find-day-of-week-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dates = array("Sunday",
               "Monday",
               "Tuesday",
               "Wednesday",
               "Thursday",
               "Friday",
               "Saturday"
              );

echo $dates[date("w")];
```

That should word nicely.

EDIT:  Come to think of it, just using `echo date("l")` should work just fine for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. The text I need to display is something particular, not just the name of the day :-)

Comment: Not a problem!  If you like my answer, please feel free to click the green checkmark to the left.  You can also ask me about any followup questions you might have.  :)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this:

---

1. You can just use `l` in [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) (lowercase **L**):

```
echo date('l');
```

---

2. You could use an [`array`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

```
$days = array(
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday");
```

and then access it with:

```
echo $days[$d];
```

---

3. You can use a [`switch`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

```
switch ($d)
{
    case 0:
        echo "Sunday";
    ...
}
```

however, I tend to avoid `switch` statements as they are the hardest for the human brain to comprehend.

---

Some tips:

1. You misspelled Tuesday
2. Use `else if` instead of multiple `if`s.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array:

```
$days_of_week = array(
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday");

echo $days_of_week[$d]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date ('l');
```

As per the [PHP manpage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

**l** (lowercase 'L'):  A full textual representation of the day of the week

Answer (score 0):

You could always look into the [switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php), something like:

```
$d=date('w');
switch($d) {
    case(0):
        $day='Sunday';
        break;
    case(1):
        $day='Monday';
        break;
    case(2):
        $day='Tuesday';
        break;
    case(3):
        $day='Wednesday';
        break;
    case(4):
        $day='Thursday';
        break;
    case(5):
        $day='Friday';
        break;
    case(6):
        $day='Saturday';
        break;
    default:
        $day=null;
}
if($day!==null) {echo($day);}
```

Comment: Why not just echo it in the switch?

Comment: Because that code should, at least imho, be used in a function and not directly in a view, and the function should not echo but return the name. That way you can use the same function also when you want only the first few letters.