# Show Day of The week in PHP from field

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi Guys im Kinda stuck with 1 part of my PHP File, i have everything else setup working the way i need it, just this bit i am stuck on

i have the follow row setup

```
echo "<td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='" . $color . "'><font size='" . $fontsize . "'>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
```

i want to show it as a Day, for Example 02/06/2013 will show as Sunday rather than the full date

i have already have

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712761/how-to-find-day-of-week-in-php

Answer (score 3):

You can use the DateTime class and format it.

```
$date = new DateTime($row['date']);
echo $date->format('d/m/Y'); // will print 02/06/2013
echo $date->format('l'); // will print a day like Sunday
```

Or just use the date function:

```
echo date('d/m/Y', $row['date']); // will print 02/06/2013
echo date('l', $row['date']); // will print a day like Sunday
```

[Check the date manual for more info.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: The asker wanted the day of the week, not the full date output. That being said, you did provide a useful step towards the solution (providing DateTime)

Comment: I've misunderstood the question, already edited the answer :) @ChrisForrence

Answer (score 3):

You can use [date_format](http://php.net/date_format):

```
$date = new DateTime($row['date']);
echo $date->format('l');
```

In case you date string does not get parsed correctly, you can use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", $row['date']);
echo $date->format('l');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTime::createFromFormat` its safer

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y","02/06/2013")->format("l");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just format your date correctly:-

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $row['date']);
echo "<td>" . $date->format('l') . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have an array of the days name:

```
 $days = array(
                1 => 'Monday',
                2 => 'Tuesday',
                3 => 'Wednesday',
                4 => 'Thursday',
                5 => 'Friday',
                6 => 'Saturday',
                0 => 'Sunday');
```

and use function `$dw = date( "w", $timestamp);`  (w will return 0 for sunday, to 6 for saturday) in php 4

or function `$dw = date("N", $timestamp);` ( N will return 1 or monday, to 7 for sunday) in php 5 ( pay attention at your array of days to change there too)

compare your $dw with your element array and print what you want. Satisfied?

Comment: There are in-built classes/methods for doing this without resorting to an array like this. Take a look at the other answers for better methods. PHP 4 is not mentioned in the OP, so no need to go to the trouble of catering for an unsupported version of PHP.

Comment: I was writing while the other answers came so I havent seen them in time. And that was my solution. Now I agree with some others answer. Thanks.