# Cron check if sunday, then die

Tags: php, symfony1

i have a cron task written in php and I want to check if the day is Sunday, then call die,

I wrote it like this :

```
if(date('w', strtotime('sunday'))) {
        die;
}
```

But looks as if it is wrong, as `echo date('w', strtotime('sunday'))` is returning zero (0).

Comment: use `if(strtolower(date('l')) == 'sunday') die()`

Comment: Yes, `date('w')` is supposed to return `0` for a Sunday.

Comment: If using `date('w')` remember, it will return a week day _number_ starting from `0` where `0` is **sunday**

Comment: `date` returns a string so it would return `'0'` and not `0`

Comment: Why would you do that? Just don't schedule the job on sundays, execution time of cronjobs is crons domain after all, that includes weekdays (the fifth time field).

Answer (score 1):

The `w` of [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is supposed to return 0 if it's sunday.

**Quote from manual:**

> w | Numeric representation of the day of the week | 0 (for Sunday) through
>   6 (for Saturday)

Use a lowercase L instead of w.

> l (lowercase 'L') | A full textual representation of the day of the
>   week | Sunday through Saturday

Or change your code to

```
if(date('w') == 0)
    die();
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just

```
if(date('w') == 0) die();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take look at this [How to find day of week in php in a specific timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712761/how-to-find-day-of-week-in-php/712923#712923) and [php date document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) maybe useful.

`date('w')` return number from 0 (Sunday) to 6(Saturday),the second parameter is `timestamp`,by default it's current time stamp `time()`.