# Issue in get the start and end dates of all weeks between two dates in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

i want to display all week dates in between choosing start date to end date so i try following code

```
 <? 

 $signupweek='2015-05-21';
 /*start day*/
 for($i = 0; $i <7 ; $i++)
{
 $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-".$i."days", strtotime($signupweek)));
 $dayName = date('D', strtotime($date));
 if($dayName == "Sun")
 {
   echo "start day is ". $date."<br>";
 }
}
?>
```

when i run  above code it gives only date like before 7 days to start date but i want to result like below

```
sDate = '2013-02-25',
eDate = '2013-03-25';
```

**Output**

```
2013-02-25                
2013-03-04                 
2013-03-11
```

any idea how can i make it possible ? your suggestions is appreciable.

***EDIT***

As per **someOne** answer i get result which i want but now i make some little bit change on that like , now if i entered **start_date =2015-04-01 and end_date=2015-05-01** so i need output like below

```
2015-04-08
2015-04-15
2015-04-22
2015-04-29
```

i don't need **start_date=2015-04-01** in my output list .is it possible in below function ?

Comment: will this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712761/how-to-find-day-of-week-in-php-in-a-specific-timezone

Comment: Anthony Lopez : i have **start_date** and **end_date** , so i need **all week dates in between this two dates** , but in your reference link there are no any suitable solution as per my requirement.

Comment: `WHERE (date_field BETWEEN '2010-01-30 14:15:55' AND '2010-09-29 10:15:55')` since you tagged as mysql and this is only an example. Google "dates between mysql" and you'll find a whole bunch of results. Then there's http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between with more examples.

Comment: Fred -ii : i know that i can get data between two date but my requirement is something different **i need only all week date values not in all date value which comes in my start_date and end_date**

Comment: Don't you think you've missed `'2013-03-18'` and even maybe `'2013-03-25'` in the required output?

Comment: someOne : yes you r right these  two dates **2013-03-18** and **2013-03-25** also will come in my output so any idea how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the edit and the request of the OP, the following new function is provided, which enables the user to specify whether or not to include the starting or ending dates in the final result using the optional arguments of `$includeFrom` and `$includeTo` respectively:

```
function getWeeklyDates2($from, $to, $includeFrom = false, $includeTo = true) {
    $from = strtotime($from);
    $to = strtotime($to);

    if($includeFrom===false)
        $from = strtotime("+7 day", $from);

    $dates = array();

    $current = $from;
    while($includeTo ? $current <= $to : $current < $to) {
        $dates[] = $current;
        $current = strtotime("+7 day", $current);
    }
    return $dates;
}

$dates2 = getWeeklyDates2('2015-04-01', '2015-04-29', false, true);
foreach($dates2 as $date)
    echo date("Y-m-d", $date) ."<br />";
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to get the dates of every next week:

```
<?php
function getWeeklyDates($from, $to) {
    $from = strtotime($from);
    $to = strtotime($to);

    $dates = array();
    $current = $from;
    while($current <= $to) {
        $dates[] = $current;
        $current = strtotime("+7 day", $current);
    }
    return $dates;
}

$dates = getWeeklyDates('2013-02-25', '2013-03-25');
foreach($dates as $date)
    echo date("Y-m-d", $date) ."<br />";
?>
```

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya And about commenting on StackOverflow, you may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) useful, and your welcome :)